# Бесконечное мигание картинки

Tags: jquery, javascript

html-код

```
<img id="help" src="images/help.png" width="16" height="16" />
```

js-код

```
var intervalID;
$("#help").mouseover(function(){
    intervalID = setInterval(function(){
        $("#help").fadeTo(300,.5);
    }, 10)
});

$("#help").mouseout(function(){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
});
```

Из этого следует, что картинка мигает бесконечно, после того как на нее навели курсор, т.е. когда уводим с картинки курсор, то мигание не перестает. Но вроде как не должно быть. Подскажите, как сделать?

Comment: @Сергей Сидоренко, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Сергей Сидоренко, мигает потому, что у вас создается о-о-очень большая очередь анимаций, т.к. в интервале 10 - это миллисекунды. А одна анимация продолжается 300 миллисекунд.

Comment: Благодарю!! Врубился!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Она вообще не должна мигать. По вашему коду. А должна тупо погаснуть до определенного значения. Но да, [[@lampa](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa) прав: много-много раз.
2. Используйте остановку анимации и callback у функций анимации.

Типа того:

http://jsfiddle.net/4wh3c36e/